# how to show contents of a MySQL table in HTML using jsp

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I am an absolute beginner in programming and I have this task: show the content of a table from MySql database in an web page. I am trying to use this code taken from a tutorial:

html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spettacoli disponibili</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Lista dei teatri</h2>
        <form method="post" action="Teatri.jsp"></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

teatri.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Lista dei teatri</title>
</head>
<body>

<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/teatro"
     user="root"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from teatri;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
   <th>Teatro</th>
   <th>Indirizzo</th>
   <th>Citta</th>
   <th>Provincia</th>
   <th>Telefono</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
   <td><c:out value="${row.nome}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.indirizzo}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.citta}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.provincia}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.telefono}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

But it doesen't work for me, the page open but the table is not shown.
Were I am wrong?

Comment: Any error on the logs?

Answer (score 0):

**"password" attribute is missing** in sql:setDataSource tag.You need to add it.

```
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/teatro"
     user="root"
     password="Your DB Password"/>
```